# Stop draggable element from appearing below, and make contents in the image

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to create contents in the image, and stop the draggable window to appear below. Z-index dosen't work. It destroys the font (probably) and breaks the title. Any other methods that don't cause problems? I will appreciate the help if you solve this.
If you wanna know the project is, It's a windows-98/95 like thing. I will change the project's name soon.
And please note: The font only works on the website. (https://oli.neocities.org/windows97/)

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/9p28gLvb/

````
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://oli.neocities.org/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    <script>
      $( function() {
    $('#window').draggable({containment:"#Image"}); 

  } );
    </script>
    <style>
img {
  contain: content;
}
    #window {
      background-color: #B9BABD;
      height: 162px;
      width: 404px;
      font-family: 'Normal';
     
    }
    .windowtitle {
      background: rgb(2,0,36);
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
      width: 404px;
      height: 20px;
      font-size: 16px;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Normal';
    }
    
    .windowbody {
    }
    
    
    button {
      display: block;
      background-color: #B9BABD;
      border-color: black;
      font-family: 'Normal';
    }
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'Normal';
  src: url('https://oli.neocities.org/windows97/fonts/normal.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
  <img src="https://oli.neocities.org/windows97/images/background.png" id="Image" style="background-size: cover; width:100%;height:100%;">
  <div id="window">
  <div class="windowtitle">
  <b>System</b>
  </div>
  <div class="windowbody">
  <center>
<div style="clear: left;">
    <p style="float: left;"><img src="/windows97/images/bubble_i.png" height="48" width="48"></p>
    &nbsp;
    <p>Zoom to 67% for the best experience.</p>
</div>
</center>
  <center>
  <button>OK</button>
  </center>
  </div>
  </div>
  </img>

  </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

fixed it

i made an container..

(edit: i'm currently working on the project, will get code later.)

Comment: Can you offer code showing your solution?